# How do I solve $\int\frac{x}{(x^2+x+1)^{\frac{1}{12}}}\,dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to solve  $$\int_0^1\frac{x}{(x^2+x+1)^{\frac{1}{12}}}\mathrm dx$$ To calculate it I first tried to calculate the primitive function. So let $$\int\frac{x}{(x^2+x+1)^{\frac{1}{12}}}\mathrm dx$$ first I added $+1-1$ to numerator then split it and tried to obtain the derivative of $x^2+x+1$ on numerator after this passages I obtain $$=\frac{6}{11}(x^2+x+1)^{\frac{11}{12}}-\frac12\int\frac{1}{(x^2+x+1)^{\frac{1}{12}}}\mathrm dx$$ My problem starts here: how can I deal with the last integral $$\int\frac{1}{(x^2+x+1)^{\frac{1}{12}}}\mathrm dx$$ I tried to substitute $(x^2+x+1)^{\frac{1}{2}}=x+t$ but it makes it more complex..Then wolphram says that we can't express it by elementary function. How can I proceed? ***Note that the book where I found the integral asks to calculate it from $0$ to $1$ and it reports a solution which is $$\frac12(\sqrt{3}-\frac72+\frac{3}{2(1+2\sqrt{3})}+\ln(1+2\sqrt{3}))$$***.Thank you in advance

Comment: If the numerator would have been $x+\dfrac12,$ then a simple substitution would have yielded a beautiful result. As it currently stands, it is unapproachable.

Comment: The integral is not expressible through a combination of elementary functions.

Comment: I've just checked on wolphram, but I find it strange since the book where I found the integral report a solution. Actually the book asks to solve it in $[0,1]$ so it asks to solve a definite integral. Anyway the problem remains the same

Comment: which book do you mean? what is the definite integral of it?

Comment: It is a book of calculus of the course I am following and it asks to calculate the integral in $[0,1]$ and it reports a solution (which obviously is a real number) that I can't find.

Comment: Solving a definite integral over some well chosen interval is *not* equivalent to finding a primitive function! There are plenty of methods to tackle a definite integral, for see for instance [contour integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_contour_integration). Hopefully someone will take the time to tackle this one.

Comment: I've written the solution reported by my book to help who wants to answer my question

Comment: @Dipok $$\frac12\left(\sqrt{3}-\frac72+\frac{3}{2(1+2\sqrt{3})}+\ln(1+2\sqrt{3})\right)\approx 0.032066326123103502203$$ Now see [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%5Bx%2F%28x%5E2%2Bx%2B1%29%5E%281%2F12%29%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C1%7D%5D)

Comment: I will try to contact the author of the book who is a person that I know and probably he will explain me how to solve it. Anyway at the moment the problem remains the same.. How can we reach the solution?

Comment: can you please post a picture of the page where this integral shows up?

Answer (score 0):

Mathematica 11.1 gives that this integral is equal to 
$$
\frac{2}{11} \left(i 3^{17/12} \, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{11}{6};\frac{23}{12};\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i \sqrt{3}}{2}\right)-i \sqrt{3} \, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{11}{6};\frac{23}{12};\frac{1}{6} \left(3+i
   \sqrt{3}\right)\right)-3+ 3^{23/12}\right)
$$
the function of interest is then 
$$
_2F_1\left(1,\frac{11}{6};\frac{23}{12};x\right) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(\frac{23}{12})\Gamma(\frac{11}{6}+n)}{\Gamma(\frac{11}{6})\Gamma(\frac{23}{12}+n)}x^n
$$
Removing the complex terms we can also the write this as 
$$
\frac{6}{11} \left( 3^{11/12} -1 + 3^{5/12}\frac{\Gamma(\frac{23}{12})}{\Gamma(\frac{11}{6})}\underbrace{\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(\frac{11}{6}+n)}{\Gamma(\frac{23}{12}+n)}\left(3^{-\frac{11}{12}-\frac{n}{2}}\sin\left(\frac{n \pi}{6}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{3}\right)\right)}_{Q}\right)
$$
so if you want a closed form you need to work out the value of $Q$, which doesn't look super promising.

Edit: After playing with this we can write the sum as 
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{x}{(x^2+x+1)^(1/12)}\;dx = \frac{1}{\Gamma(\frac{1}{12})}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}B\left(-1,2+2k,\frac{11}{12}-k\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{12}-k\right)= 0.47017004410654...
$$
where $B$ is the incomplete beta function.